# Reducing system of odes to a single differential equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

I have the system of equations:
$$\begin{array}{l}
x(r)=a y(r)^{b} \qquad\qquad (1)\\
\frac{d x(r)}{d r}=-c \frac{z(r) y(r)}{r^{2}} \qquad\ \ (2) \\
\frac{d z(r)}{d r}=k\ r^{2} y(r) \qquad\quad(3)
\end{array}$$
Where $a,b,c,k$ are constants. I managed to reduce this to a single differential equation in $y(r)$, but how can I reduce it to a single equation in $x(r)$ or $z(r)$?

How I solved for $y$:

Taking the derivative wrt. $r$ of the first equation:
$$\tag{4}
\frac{d x}{d r}=\frac{d}{d r} a y^{b}=a y^{b-1} \frac{d y}{d r}
$$
And from eqs. $(2-3)$:
$$\tag{5}
\frac{r^{2}}{y} \frac{d x}{d r}=-c z \Rightarrow \frac{d}{d r}\left(\frac{r^{2}}{y} \frac{d x}{d r}\right)=-c k r^{2} y
$$
Substituting $(4)$ into $(5)$:
$$\frac{d}{d r}\left(r^2 a y^{b-2} \frac{d y}{d r}\right)=-c k r^{2} y$$

Comment: You mean $\dfrac{dz(r)}{dr}$ at the last line?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: Maybe show us what you have tried? I would like to know how you this system (?) to a single DE in $y(r)$.

Comment: I added how i solved in terms of $y$. It is not super pretty, but that is not strictly necessary.